# Angular ui-routing and multiple views in nested child states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I have a parent state that is abstract which basically only contains a template html that has ui-views. I have multiple child states that contains multiple views, and each of the child states has child states which also contains multiple views. The first child state in the line works fine but when I try to access the child state to the child state then it crashes.

Here's some code simplified (I have several components in on page in the real code. It works like todo. It basicly has a list and a edit view (I don't want in row/in line edit for the list) and the edit view will show/hide depending on the state your in of editing a single item or creating new item. I want rest of the lists for the other components to be still showing up):

index.html:

```
<div ui-view></div>
<div ui-view="todo-edit"></div>
<div ui-view="todo-list"></div>
```

js code:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('root', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/index.html'
    })
    .state('root.todo', { //This state works
        url: '/todo',
        views: {
            '': {
                template: 'Todo list'
            },
            'todo-list': {
                templateUrl: '/todo-list.html',
                controller: 'TodoListController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.todo.edit', { //This state does not work
        url: '/edit/:id',
        views: {
            '@root': {
                template: 'Edit todo'
            },
            'todo-list@root': {
                templateUrl: '/todo-list.html',
                controller: 'TodoListController'
            },
            'todo-edit@root': {
                templateUrl: '/todo-edit.html',
                controller: 'TodoEditController'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('root.todo.create', { //This state does not work
        url: '/create',
        views: {
            '@root': {
                template: 'Create todo'
            },
            'todo-list@root': {
                templateUrl: '/todo-list.html',
                controller: 'TodoListController'
            },
            'todo-edit@root': {
                templateUrl: '/todo-edit.html',
                controller: 'TodoEditController'
            }
        }
    });
```

The state todo.list.edit does not work and it will just return me to the root page without any errors. Anyone have any idea what the problem might be and how to solve it? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Perhaps I'm on the wrong track with views and there's another way to solve it?

I want to solve the different "states" using states and not ng-include and sharing state between a service or something simlar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've gathered you can only set the template in the states parents view container and not the parents parent. If anyone finds a solution on this then please post and I'll set it as asnwer

Answer (score 3):

You are defining 2 child states of `todo.list`:

`.state('todo.list.edit') and .state('todo.list.create')`

but I don't see where you've defined a state called `todo.list`. For that to work either define a `todo.list` state or make the 2 create and edit states children of `todo`:

`.state('todo.edit') and .state('todo.create')`

Also,

`todo.list.edit`

is not valid since your `todo` state is actually called `root.todo` so even if you have a `todo.list` state it would have to be called `root.todo.list`.

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, remaining from some code i copy/pasted inside but forgot to tidy up. I've edited it now so it's correct. Thanks for heads up. Also forgot to add root in front of them too, it's taken care of now :)

Comment: No problem. Copy and paste code, expect weird errors ;)